# What is a good way of making a list of names with associated attributes in C++?

Tags: c++, class

My question is hard to explain, but feels so fundamental that it probably has its own section in every C++ textbook: How would one go about creating a list of named variables that contain various data types in C++? I'll use an example: Lets say I am making a game and I want to spawn a billion characters. Those characters would all have unique names used to identify them, then different attributes like hp, stamina, hunger assigned to those names. how would one go about creating that code? Is the answer simply: Create a massive 2D array at the beginning of run time and just fill it up? Seems like a band-aid to me.

Classes seem like the answer I am looking for, but I cannot get past the point of how to create a virtually unending list of unique classes, because it would require assigning the name of a variable during runtime, which I am fairly certain is either impossible or impractical in c++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person {
public:
    Person() {
        int hp = 10;
        std::cout << "Enter HP: ";
        std::cin >> hp;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    bool loop = true;
    char name;
    while (loop != false) {
        std::cout << "Enter Name: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> name;
        Person (/*make the name of this class equal to the variable stored in "name"*/);
        std::cout << "Press 0 if you are done entering names." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> loop;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is knowledge about data structures.  `std::map` in particular is very useful when you want to store some data (e.g. a `Person` object) in a way that makes it easy to look up with a given well-known identifier/key (e.g. "Merlin")

Comment: Why do you need separately-named variables or separate types for each person? Just have one `Person` class, add a `std::string name;` member variable to that and then create a `std::vector` of `Person` objects.

Answer (score 3):

As you've surmised, the name of a variable is assigned at compile time, not run time.

One possibility however, would be to use something like an `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` to store some arbitrary number of items (`Person`s, in this case) associated with `string`s (or some other type, but `string` seems applicable in this case).

```cpp
class Person {
    int hp;
public:
    person(int hp) : hp(hp) {}
    void takeDamage(int hpLost) { hp -= hpLost; }
};

std::map<std::string, Person> people;

void enterPerson() { 
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Please enter your character name: ";
    std::cin >> name;

    people[name] = Person(1000);
}
```

Then if they get in a fight and take 30 h damage, we might do something like this:

```cpp
people[name].takeDamage(30);
```